# Find to how many digits the value $\frac{355}{113}$ is an accurate approximation of $3.1415929204$.

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Find to how many digits the value $\frac{355}{113}$ is an accurate approximation of $3.1415929204$.

What i did was i computed it using a calculator and got the of $\frac{355}{113}$ to be

$3.14159265$

Now i see that up to the $6$th decimal place they are same. So i write as up to $6$ digits the value of $\frac{355}{113}$ is the same as a given approximation of $\pi$.

Am i right? Is this the way to do these type of questions?

Thanks.

Comment: Given you've picked numerical-methods and approximation as tags, I'd suggest that the right _method_ for doing this would be to calculate $|335/113 - 31415929204/10000000000|$ and look for an answer of the form $p/10^n$.  Then $n-1$ is the number of decimal places of accuracy that you have.

Comment: Note: it depends on what you mean by an accurate match for the least significant digit - whether rounding is supposed to be done for either or both numbers. For example, if I round $355/113$ to the number of digits suggested I get $3$ as the final estimated digit rather than $2$.

Comment: In general, the following is valid. Since you have to memorize six digits for the continued fraction convergent $\frac{355}{113}$, then you will have something with six digits of decimal accuracy. And that is exactly true for this particular convergent.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the matching sequence is "3.141592".

You are correct that the approximation is accurate **up to 6 decimal places**, but I believe the **number of digits** should be 7, if that is what the question is asking.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Sam.

I want to add that that number is quite famous (Buffon's needle). You can see it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle#Estimating_.CF.80